# sql remove common from two select statements

Tags: sql, select, compare

I am trying to make an SQL Select query, where I can see all employees that are working today.

**The first query selects all employees:**

```
SELECT      Medarbejdere.navn AS Medarbejder
FROM        Medarbejdere
```

**The other select shows the employees that are not at work.**

```
SELECT      Medarbejdere.navn AS Medarbejder
FROM        Medarbejdere, Fravaer
WHERE       Medarbejdere.id = Fravaer.medarbejder
AND         Fravaer.slut IS NULL
```

How can I combine the two select statements, so the employees that are not at work today are removed from the complete list of employees (the first select statement)?

I tried with UNION and JOINS.

Any suggestions?

Edit-->
**This actually works, but I would like to make it work with JOIN**

```
SELECT      Medarbejdere.navn AS Medarbejder
FROM        Medarbejdere
EXCEPT
SELECT      Medarbejdere.navn AS Medarbejder
FROM        Medarbejdere, Fravaer
WHERE       Medarbejdere.id = Fravaer.medarbejder
AND         Fravaer.slut IS NULL
```

Fravaer (absence) without an end date (those I am trying to filter out)

```
INSERT INTO Fravaer VALUES (3, '2018-08-01', null, 4);
```

or absence with an end date (those I am trying to include)

```
INSERT INTO Fravaer VALUES (6, '2018-08-01', '2018-09-01', 5);
```

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what columns names define, but just to give you some idea. Find Employees who are not in the not working list.

You can also use Left join and see which one is faster.

```
-- dummy query based on your inputs

SELECT      Medarbejdere.navn AS Medarbejder
FROM        Medarbejdere
where Medarbejdere.id not in (
SELECT      Medarbejdere.id
FROM        Medarbejdere, Fravaer
WHERE       Medarbejdere.id = Fravaer.medarbejder
AND         Fravaer.slut IS NULL )

-- second option, based on sample data
SELECT *
FROM    Medarbejdere m
LEFT JOIN Fravaer f
    ON f.medarbejder = m.ID
WHERE f.slut IS NOT NULL and f.slut>= '2018-09-01'; //you can use generic 
currentdate option
```

Comment: Hi Iti - That actually works ! Would you be able to make it with a JOIN instead?

Comment: Did you tried using your second query with not null? what does it results in?

Comment: That results in an output with all the absence that there is. Also the absence that has ended.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `LEFT` join:

```
SELECT *
FROM    Medarbejdere m
    LEFT JOIN Fravaer f
        ON f.medarbejder = m.ID
WHERE f.ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. The f.id should be f.slut       (slut means end i danish). I know it's a bit more difficult to code when I use local language. Hope its ok. But, it doesn't work, because it also includes employees, who has been away from work, where the NULL is a date.